# Previous States - bayesian networks

Tags: r, markov-process, bayesian-network

I have data in the following format for transition of people between various places

1. A to B : 100
2. A to C : 50
3. B to C : 10
4. B to A : 2
5. C to D : 60

and so on

I dont have frequencies of complete journeys but only frequencies between 2 places.

Now I understand that in Bayes Nets the assumption is that the next step depends only on the current step and not previous steps.

So I can in fact use the above data even though I dont have complete journeys for every person. Is my understanding correct? If so please could you point out some packages in R where this can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

" the next step depends only on the current step and not previous steps" this is Markov assumption and it is not generally true in a Bayesian network.
Here is a [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRain/vignettes/gRain-intro.pdf) for Bayesian network.